# Make whole line in a ListView clickable?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have some problems with my ListView. At fist I build my project for android v2.2. No I build the same one in v2.1. My Problem is now, that in my listview no longer the whole line is clickable but only the text is clickable. How could I make my whole line clickable again?

Alex

Edit: I use a simple adapter.

Edit2:
My code:

```
setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter <String> (myEvents.this, R.layout.list_item, titleList));

    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // here is an alert dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: are you putting the click handler onto the view returned from the getView() method in the adapter? or on the list itself?  or just the textview?

Comment: @alexvii can u post ur sample code ....As this problem generally arises when you are using custom listview i.e in one line there are more than one widget(editext,checkbox,textview etc.)...if there is only textview and u are using normal listview then onItemClickListener may be will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this...

override the getview of the simple adapter like shown in [this link](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/).

In the adapter..

```
View getView(......)
{
    // set the tag of the text view object
    textView.setTag(data);
    textView.setOnClickListner(myOnClick);

}
```

Member on click listener.

```
public OnClick myOnClick = new Onclick(

    void onclick(View v)
    {
        Object data = view.getTag();
        // do something based on the data..
    }

);
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Instead of using the arrayadapter you need to override the getView method of the array adapter. I have provided a link in my answer for helping you to do that. If you have any particular troubles doing the same then please ask.