# not whole list item is clickable in the ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Yes I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761726/make-whole-line-in-a-listview-clickable) question. No it didn't help.

The problem is that only the highlighted area of my `ListView` cell is clickable. It is the area that is filled with text. Take a look on the picture:

[image]

So when you click on the circled area - it wouldn't respond.

Any ideas on how to make it work properly???

**Edit:** my list layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shoulderLogo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shoulderLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show the layout you are inflating for each list item?

Comment: Is that an image or are you using something like customized adapters?
Would you mind to post the xml layout

Comment: If you are not inflating it then try to remove margins in the xml file if any

Comment: Please, take a look on the edit. Does it help?

Comment: and even the listview xml file would be of help i think

Comment: Change the layout to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because your list layout LinearLayout has a `layout_width` of `wrap_content`.  This will cause your row to only be as wide as the views contained within.  If you set it instead to `fill_parent` or `match_parent` it will extend to fill the width of your list.

Comment: What if I have an ImaageView next to the textView? Fill_Parent doesn't cover that thing then!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/shoulderLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shoulderLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! :) BUT change android:layout_width = "100dp" in the ImageView :)